# Spatie laravel-data, how can i pass expression to validation attribute argument?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to pass a **date('Y') + 1** as value to the **Max** attribute, but the IDE highlights the error
*"Constant expression contains invalid operations"*. Is there any way I can get around this or do I need to create a separate rule?

```
public function __construct
(
    #[Required]
    public readonly string $vin,

    #[Required, Digits(4), IntegerType, Min(1900), Max(date('Y')+1)]
    public readonly string $year
) {
    
}
```